# Can create SCHEMABINDING view by SQL Server Management Studio tool

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know can create SCHEMABINDING view in SQL Server Management Studio tool.

I have tried create view by code like below but I get this error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'test2' because name 'tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

Code for creating view is like below:

```
CREATE VIEW test2 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
    SELECT 
        d.[Project No], d.Originator, d.Zone, d.Unit, d.Discipline, 
        dis.DiscDesc, d.[Document Type], d.[Owner Document Number], d.[Sazeh 
  Document Number], 
        d.[IDENTIFICATION CODE1], d.[IDENTIFICATION CODE2], d.[Document Title], 
        d.SheetNumber, charindex('(', t.[Owner Document Number]) - 1 AS Doc_Visual_pos, 
        IIF(charindex('(', t.[Owner Document Number]) - 1 > 0, LEFT(t.[Owner Document Number], charindex('(', t.[Owner Document Number]) - 1), t.[Owner Document Number]) AS Doc_Visual, 
        t.REV, t.POI, p.[Purpose of Issue Description], 
        t.CC, t.[Int-Tr-NO], t.[To-Owner-Tr-No], t.[MC-CSheet-No], t.AcCode, 
        t.Pages, t.PaperSize, t.SJC_TO_MC_Let_NO, t.MC_TO_SJC_Let_No, 
        t.To_FEng_Tr_No, t.SJC_Tr_No, t.Ext_Int, t.[Early Planned Issue Date], 
        t.[Late Planned Issue Date], t.[Tag-No], t.Phase, t.SubPhase, 
        t.ActivityID, t.Manhour, t.WorkPackage, t.[DCN-No], t.[DCR-No], 
        t.[DCR-Reason], t.Remark, t.LastRevPerDoc, t.LastRevPerPOI, 
        t.HoldBy, t.CommentID, t.ExTrID, t.HT_TR_No, t.Recipients, 
        t.MC_HD_Comment_No, t.[CT-Transmittals], ct.[CT_CS_Tr-Date], 
        t.DefaultForDocument, t.HyperDoc, t.root
    FROM 
        tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo AS ct 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        (((tblDocuments AS d 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblTransmittals AS t ON d.[Owner Document Number] = t.[Owner Document Number])
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblPurposeofIssue AS p ON t.POI = p.[Purpose of Issue]) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblDiscipline AS dis ON d.Discipline = dis.DiscCode) ON ct.CT_CS_Tr_No = t.[CT- Transmittals];
```

Comment: Use schema in your view definition. I.e. instead of tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo use dbo.tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo or whatelse schema is

Comment: You are also missing parenthesis around your select statement, you can remove the closing ; and replace with )

Comment: thanks, my problem solved. if i want to create a index on (Doc_Visual) field because i need searching on this view which index i have to use, this field is not unique.

Comment: I would personally use this view to decant into a table and then apply your index to the table, then put an overlying view on top of the indexed table. You can read more on what Index would be suitable from many online resources, some are SQL version specific, here are Microsoft's list. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described